# Getting a permision error to write over a closed file

Tags: python

I'm getting a permision error over a file I previously read with a With open statement and can't figure out why. I simplified the small program as much as I could without deleting stuff where the error might be but I can't see. The error is in the encpryption() function at the end.

I tested if the file was closed by adding f.readlines outside of the with open statement and got the trying to read a closed file error.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
import time
from tkinter import *
#from tkinter.tix import *
import win32api
import random
import string
from random import randrange
import codecs
import string_utils


filename = "int.txt"




def encryption():   #This function encrypts a password entered by the user




    random_number = randrange(50,100)
    print(random_number)

    char_set = string.ascii_lowercase + string.digits 
    random_char1 =(''.join(random.sample(char_set*6, random_number)))

    char_set = string.ascii_uppercase + string.digits 
    random_char2 =(''.join(random.sample(char_set*6, random_number)))

    char_set = string.ascii_lowercase + string.digits 
    random_char3 =(''.join(random.sample(char_set*6, 75)))

    char_set = string.ascii_uppercase + string.digits 
    random_char4 =(''.join(random.sample(char_set*6, 75)))
    


    random_char = random_char1 + random_char2

    random_char_defined = random_char3 + random_char4


    random_shuffle = string_utils.shuffle(random_char)

    random_shuffle_defined = string_utils.shuffle(random_char_defined)

    print(random_shuffle + "string1")

    print(random_shuffle_defined + "string2")



    user_email = e.get()
    user_password = e2.get()
    
    print(user_password)

    encoded_password_0 = codecs.encode(user_password,'rot_13')
    print(encoded_password_0+ "lalalala")

    salted_password = random_shuffle_defined + encoded_password_0 + random_shuffle

    salted_len = len(encoded_password_0)

    print(salted_len)

    with open(filename,"w+") as f:  #I'm getting an error here PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'int.txt'
        f.write(user_email+"\n")
        f.write(salted_password+"\n")
        f.write(str(salted_len))
        print("I created the file")




def cs_open():


    PATH = "C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe"
    options = Options()
    options.headless = False



    driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH,options = options) 
    driver.maximize_window()
    
    driver.implicitly_wait(10)

    user_email = e.get()
    user_password = e2.get()

    print(user_email)
    print(user_password)

    driver.get("https://www.compraensanjuan.com")
    


    link = driver.find_element_by_link_text("Mi cuenta")

    link.click()
    

    email = driver.find_element_by_name("email")

    email.send_keys(user_email)

    print("I sent the keys")




    password = driver.find_element_by_name("clave")

    password.send_keys(user_password)
    password.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)

    print("I sent the keys2")

    encryption()

FILE_ATTRIBUTE_HIDDEN = 0x02
Attribute = FILE_ATTRIBUTE_HIDDEN 
win32api.SetFileAttributes(filename,Attribute)

with open(filename) as f:
    hola = f.readlines()
    print(hola)
    user_email_1 = hola[0].replace("\n","")
    print("now im here")
    print(user_email_1)
    user_password_1 = hola[1].replace("\n","")
    print(user_password_1)
    password_len = hola[2].replace("\n","")
    print(password_len)



    password_building = user_password_1[150:(150+int(password_len))]

    print(password_building+ "  the first pass")
    password_building_decrypted = codecs.decode(password_building,"rot_13")
    user_password_1 = password_building_decrypted
    print(user_password_1 +   "  the pass")




root = Tk()
root.title("CSBOT")

CSBOT_label = Label(root, text= "Actualiza automáticamente tus publicaciones de Compra En San Juan")
space_label = Label(root,text="")

CSBOT_label.pack()
space_label.pack()

email_label = Label(root, text = "Ingrese su Email")
email_label.pack()


e = Entry(root, width= 50)
e.pack()
e.insert(0,user_email_1)
password_label = Label(root, text = "Ingrese su Contraseña")
password_label.pack()


e2 = Entry(root, width = 50, show= "*")
e2.pack()
e2.insert(0,user_password_1)


#tooltip_update = Balloon(root)
#tooltip_update.bind_widget(actulizar_button, balloonmsg = "Recuerde NO minimizar la ventana del navegador mientras la actualización automática esta en proceso")




open_button = Button(root,text= "Abrir Sin Actualizar", command= cs_open)
open_button.pack()


root.mainloop()
```

FULL TRACEBACK:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\asdf\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1883, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "stack.py", line 123, in cs_open
    encryption()
  File "stack.py", line 70, in encryption
    with open(filename,"w+") as f:
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'int.txt'
```

Comment: You should fix your code's indentation, and include the _full_ stacktrace including the actual line that produced the error.

Comment: Looks like some missing indentation errors crept in with the simplifying. 

Do you know the working directory when running the program. It might be as simple as the process not having the permission to write in that directory.

Comment: Corrected indentation, added fulltraceback.

Comment: Highly recommend reducing this code to the simplest case that reproduces the problem.  There's a lot of code here that has no relation to the question.

Comment: the not simplified part of the program uses the encryption() function and writes without any problems (for something else). So, I think it's not a folder permssion problem.

Comment: I didn't cut more stuff in fear of deleting something important that causes the error that I might have not noticed.

Comment: That's part of the debugging process.  If it goes away, investigate what you cut.  You'll likely solve it yourself and learn something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've set the file to hidden.  A quick tests shows that's the reason it won't open for writing, but reading works:

```
C:\>echo >test

C:\>attrib +h test

C:\>py
Python 3.9.1 (tags/v3.9.1:1e5d33e, Dec  7 2020, 17:08:21) [MSC v.1927 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> open('test','w+')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'test'
>>> open('test')
<_io.TextIOWrapper name='test' mode='r' encoding='cp1252'>
```

Comment: This actually did it for me, thank you. I started deleting stuff to see if I could find the error and even though I deleted the set hidden part, I didnt realize that the file would still be hiden until set visible so I kept getting the error anyway rofl.

Comment: Luckily you pointed it out because I was about to copy and paste a way more compact version of the program in the post without the set hidden part

Comment: @AshienteAni Yes, generally keep the parts that actually touch the file :^)